# Can't Read One Int at a Time from Binary File

Tags: c++, io

I am learning about C++ IO operations and have run into trouble reading from a binary file. I initialize an array with 100 random values, and write the values in the array to a `.bin` file. I think I got that part down -for some reason though my `.bin` file size is 1600 bytes instead of 400- but am struggling with reading the values.

I thought it was possible to read int by int by iterating through the `memblock` array containing the read values, but my console output shows a single random number followed by a bunch of zeroes. I would appreciate your guidance.

```
// reading a binary file int by int 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    FILE * pFile; 
    streampos size;
    int * memblock;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[100];

    //data to write initially stored in array
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        array[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    pFile = fopen("writebinary.bin","wb");
    fwrite(array,sizeof(int),sizeof(array),pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

    ifstream readFile("writebinary.bin",ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (readFile.is_open()){
        size = readFile.tellg();
        //allocate memory to read file contents
        memblock = new int[size];
        readFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){ //100 because there are 100 ints,I'm assuming 32 bits are read a at a time from writebinary.bin
            readFile.read((char*)memblock,sizeof(int));
        }
        readFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "can't open file " << endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        cout << memblock[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing and reading *one* `int`?

Comment: You shouldn't be use "ios::ate" when reading from the file.

Comment: yes, that is working fine

Comment: what's wrong with using ios::ate?

Comment: You are reading all 100 numbers into the first element of `memblock`.

Comment: *doh , thanks a lot. I changed the code to `readFile.read((char*)(memblock+i),sizeof(int));` and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for your first issue, `sizeof(array)` is 400, because your array of 100 ints takes up 400 bytes, and `sizeof(int)` is 4, because an int is 32 bits. That's why you get a 1600 byte output file. You are hardcoding the number 100 everywhere else; you need to hardcode it here as well, or use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)`.

Second, you don't need to iterate when using istream::read. It needs the size of the buffer to read, in bytes. So do `readFile.read((char *)memblock,sizeof(array));` just once.

On another note, though, your code is a mish-mash of C-style programming and C++ iostreams programming. Why use fopen/fwrite/fclose? You should use std::ofstream and use the [write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) member function, analogous to your `readFile.read`.

Comment: Hardcoding 100 everywhere else is not entirely accurate: `new int[tellg()]` makes the same mistake yet again, allocating 1600 `int` objects (6400 bytes)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, I was too fast there. Good catch.

Comment: yes, thanks. the reason I used a loop was because my assignment required it eg `Perform file I/O in binary format with one value at a time`